# How to pass cloud-init file to vm in gcloud using golang?

Tags: rest, go, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cloud-init

I want to pass the yaml file (#cloud-config) to user-data in gcloud vm instance using golang. How can I do that?

```
Metadata: &compute.Metadata{
  Items: []*compute.Items{
   {Key: porto.String("user-data"),
   Value: ...userdata.yaml...?
   },
  },
},
```

compute: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances

gcp cloud-init: https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance

Creating gcp vm instance using golang - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#publicimage

Comment: Have you tried using a `Value` of the string content of the cloud-config YAML file?

Comment: That would be tedious? Would have to enter spacing, line breaks manually?

Comment: Does that mean I have to enter the string manually into ```Value```

Comment: @DazWilkin, yes that works but how can I pass all the strings within the cloud-config yaml file

Comment: No, if you have the file on host's file system, you can use something like [`os.ReadFile`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#ReadFile) to read the contents into memory as an `[]byte` and `string(...)` it to pass it as a `Value`. Alternatively, you could build the [YAML](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3) in your code, serialize it and pass that as a `Value`.

Comment: You'll need to escape control characters (`\n`) and quotes (`"`).